# After modify the table in database, local variables dose not affect?

Tags: c#, html, sql, database

I am developing a website which is for contractor management.

In the database table, a variable calls totalHours, which stores the value of the total amounts of hours the user apply for.

Originally, the datatype of totalHours was int. But, I realized that user also could apply for half hours. eg:01:30:00 / 05:00:00 etc. That is why I have changed the data type from int to time(7) to stores those half hours.

```
try { 
    ApplicationDAL applicationDAL = new ApplicationDAL(); 
    overtimeApplication myApplication = new overtimeApplication(); 
    myApplication.contractorID = contID; 
    myApplication.overtypeID = overTypeID; 
    myApplication.managerID = manID; 
    myApplication.directorID = 1; 
    myApplication.reason = reason; 
    myApplication.applicationState = applicationState; // Submit Form 
    myApplication.managerState = managerState; 
    myApplication.directorState = directorState; 
    myApplication.status = status; 
    myApplication.state = state; 
    myApplication.startDate = startDate; 
    myApplication.startTime = startingTime; 
    myApplication.endDate = endDate; 
    myApplication.endTime = endingTime; 
    myApplication.applyDate = DateTime.Now.Date; 
    myApplication.createdDate = DateTime.Now; 
    myApplication.totalHours = totalHour; 
    myApplication.docNo = docNo; 
    myApplication.projectID = projectID; 
    myApplication.actionID = 3; 
    myApplication.applicationAction = 1;
}
```

After I have changed the data type of totalHours from int to time(7) and deleted all the data of that column (to Null). The local variable in the function above should detect my changes, but it still calls me it is an int value from that table (as a show).

[The datatype in the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QglvQ.png)

[The datatype of the local variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGbpn.png)

By the way, I am new fish of this language. I would be appreciated if you could give me a hand. I have stacked in here for a week, and it is a company's project.

Comment: What kind of Data Model do you use? If you use Entity Framework, did you updated your .edmx file? did you change the data type in DB or Entity Framework or both? Please provide more details.

Comment: Hi, I have only changed the data type in DB.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Entity Framework to connect to your database, you need to update your .edmx file from your DB so the changes will be included in your model. You can find the step-by-step instruction in the following page: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/changing-the-database